# Prove the equation for the point of intersection of two vector lines

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, parametric, intersection-theory

This is my first question here and I'm not sure if it's the right place but I'm kinda desperate. I was learning about vector lines and parametric equations. My teacher gave me the assignment below and it is nothing like I saw in my lessons and when I asked him for help he didn't really help (it's an online school so communication is difficult). Here is the question word for word:

*Prove that (if exists) the point of intersection between two lines L1: r→=r01→+tu1→ , t∈R and L2: r→=r02→+su2→ , s∈R is given by the vector formula:

r→=r01→+[( r02→-r01→ )u2→] (u1→×u2→)u1→×u2→2 u1→*

Like I said, nothing similar to that was talked about in the lessons and I really have no idea of what to do or how to prove it so I was hoping someone could help me here. The arrows in the equations above mean that they are vectors.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use mathjax for your question. This [guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

First, you write your lines into vector form or in [homogeneous coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates/Line_coordinates_and_duality). According to the definition of the cross product, if the two lines are non-parallel then the resulting vector $\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}$ is perpendicular to both $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$. In addition from the definition of dot product, the dot product between the vertical vectors is $0$, so you can get:
$$\mathbf{a}^\top\cdot(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})=\mathbf{a}^\top\cdot\mathbf{p}=0$$
$$\mathbf{b}^\top\cdot(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b})=\mathbf{b}^\top\cdot\mathbf{p}=0$$
Therefore, the point $\mathbf{p}$ lies on the plane of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, and on the line $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, and $\mathbf{p}$ is the intersection of the two lines. Note $\mathbf{p}$ is the homogeneous coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Assuming your lines are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we have

$$
\cases{
L_1\to r = r_{01}+t u_1\\
L_2\to r = r_{02}+s u_2
}
$$

the possible intersection happens when $r_{01}+t u_1 = r_{02}+s u_2$ and now multiplying conveniently we have

$$
u_1\cdot r_{01}+t\|u_1\|^2 = u_1\cdot r_{02}+su_1\cdot u_2\\
u_2\cdot r_{01}+t u_2\cdot u_1 =   u_2\cdot r_{02}+s\|u_2\|^2\\
$$

and now we can try to solve for $t,s$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\|u_1\|^2 & u_1\cdot u_2\\
u_1\cdot u_2 & \|u_2\|^2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
t\\
s
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
u_1\cdot(r_{02}-r_{01})\\
u_2\cdot(r_{02}-r_{01})
\end{array}
\right)
$$

NOTE

If $u_1 = \lambda u_2$ then $\det\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\|u_1\|^2 & u_1\cdot u_2\\
u_1\cdot u_2 & \|u_2\|^2
\end{array}
\right) = 0$